# ObjectMapper.readValue can return null value?

Tags: java, json, jackson

ObjectMapper.readValue in Jackson library does return null value. In what case does it return null object? It found that from codebase.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```

You can browse through ObjectMapper class to dig in more details

Comment: _does return null value_ So you saw it return `null`? What did you try to deserialize?

Comment: So you have access to the source code? Did you follow along to see when it would return `null`?

Comment: You should always add the information to the question, so that it will be available for everyone without any efforts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`readValue()` returns `null` for JSON input consisting of JSON value `null`.
It does not return `null` for any other case: missing input (for example) would be rewarded by an exception; and no deserializer produces `null` by default.

Comment: Hi @StaxMan, do you have an example? I am trying to simulate it like so: `public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
  ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper();
  String s = "{\"id\":null}";
  SomeClass r = o.readValue(s, SomeClass.class);
  System.out.println(r);
 }`, but most probably this is not what you meant. The (documentation)[https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html] also does not have this use case, for example `readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType)`

Comment: I don't understand your question: you not passing a JSON null but JSON Object. That does not produce `null` value.

Comment: Hi @StaxMan, thanks for getting back, could you please give me an example of what you mean by JSON value `null`? Thanks.

Comment: As per JSON Specification (https://www.json.org/json-en.html), String "null". Literally, input containing just `null` (and possibly leading and/or trailing white space).

Answer (score 1):

As @StaxMan said consisting of JSON value null,the value may be "null",code should like this

```
ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper();
String s = "null";
SomeClass r = o.readValue(s, SomeClass.class);
System.out.println(r)
```